Nginx-Apache Reverse Proxy Setup: PHP Works on Port 8080 But Not on Port 80
I have a typical Nginx-Apache reverse proxy setup on my server.
Port 8080 (Apache) is working correctly for PHP files: http://130.61.139.145:8080/info.php
Port 80 (Nginx reverse proxy) does not load PHP files as expected: http://130.61.139.145/info.php
It seems like the configuration should be redirecting PHP requests from Nginx to Apache, but this isn’t working as intended.
Here's my site.conf file:
# for security reasons
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name _;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # PHP Files Processing
    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

# f2.findart.pro
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    root /var/www/f2.findart.pro;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name f2.findart.pro;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

# 130-61-139-145.nip.io - free reserve domain - !!! without CDN !!!
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name 130-61-139-145.nip.io;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/130-61-139-145.nip.io/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/130-61-139-145.nip.io/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}





Try proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080; instead. What is your host OS (could be a SELinux issue)?

I have tried and same issue. My OS is Ubuntu. Thank you

Oh, missed it first time, what for you put return 444 in your config? Of course it won't work unless you remove it.

I have tried and same issue. Thanks Ivan

Are you sure it is a given server block responds to your request? You can check it defining custom access log inside this block.

I have updated my question so you can see additional configuration now. Thank you Ivan

Ok, from what I see. The first server block should act as default server serving any HTTP requests on port 80 except those with Host header equal to f2.findart.pro or 130-61-139-145.nip.io. The second one will redirect any http://f2.findart.pro/... requests to https://f2.findart.pro/.... The third one listen on both 80 and 443 ports, redirecting both http://130-61-139-145.nip.io/... and https://130-61-139-145.nip.io/... to https://130-61-139-145.nip.io/... (making an infinite redirect loop).

BTW, using try_files inside the location with proxy_pass content handler usually makes a little sense. However I don't see any explicit error preventing this config from serving .../info.php requests.

To find out what default server is, check the How nginx processes a request article.

One more detail - the last server block, being the only one who listen on HTTPS port 443, will be a default server for every HTTPS requests, no matter what Host header value it will contain. That means you'd got an infinite redirection loop for every HTTPS requests, https://f2.findart.pro/ -> https://f2.findart.pro/, https://130-61-139-145.nip.io/ -> https://130-61-139-145.nip.io/, etc.
